# Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent Service Starts then Stops

Tags: vpn, cisco-anyconnect

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent was working until yesterday, then it suddenly stopped. I have not installed/updated any software on my PC in the past week.

When I start the Cisco AnyConnect client, I get the messages:

> VPN Service not available.
>
> The VPN agent service is not responding. Please restart this application after a minute.

My Event Log shows this information:

```
Faulting application name: vpnagent.exe, version: 3.1.5187.0, time stamp: 0x543f5ae9
Faulting module name: vpncommon.dll, version: 3.1.5187.0, time stamp: 0x543f58ef
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0005eac6
Faulting process id: 0x2a5c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d04087bc1b3ff3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnagent.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncommon.dll
Report Id: fd291387-ac7a-11e4-9545-415645000030
```

I have checked the files:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility
  Client\vpnagent.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility
  Client\vpncommon.dll

with those on a colleague's PC (where Cisco Anyconnect works) and they are identical.

I have tried moving all of the files within:

- C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

to another directory, whilst I re-installed the software, but this did not help (I have seen other post say that this resolved this issue).

Please can you tell me how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by uninstalling CISCO AnyConnect, then deleting the folder:

**C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client**

Note that this folder is hidden: **C:\ProgramData**

Then I re-installed the CISCO AnyConnect software and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You may have Internet Connection Sharing service active, like when you set your computer as a wifi hotspot. Sharing connections may prevent Cisco VPN service to run. In Windows 7 or 8, open local services configuration, look for Internet Connection Sharing service and stop it (double-click and hit "Stop"). Try starting the VPN client service again by starting the Cisco Systems Inc. VPN service. Locate the VPN executable and run it.

Hope it helps.